# Access values from a list in python

Tags: python-3.x

How would I extract the values `('text1', 'text2', 'text3', 'text4')` from the following list in python:

```
alltags=[Tag(Text='text2'), Tag(Text='text2'), Tag(Text='text3'), Tag(Text='text4')]
```

Comment: What is the `Tag` class? Maybe reading up on its documentation may help.

Comment: Are those named tuples? Just use `[x.Text for x in alltags]`

Answer (score 1):

A list comprehension should do it:

`[t.Text for t in alltags]`

Comment: Only problem is, there is no telling that the attributes of the objects would be called `Text`, although ideally it would be.

Comment: actually, I wanted to extract just [a, b, c] from following exception of a large json file.   
"alltags": {"tags”: [{"text": "a"}, {"text": "b"}, {"text": "c"}]}

In order to do this, I have executed the following code:

alltags = [tag.NewFromJsonDict(h) for h in line['alltags']['tags']]